# WIA 2.0 Escanear documentos ambos lados en Java

Tags: java, imagen, scanner

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio en java para escanear documentos y guardarlos en una base de datos o directorio, uso la librería WIA (Windows Image Acquisition) y COM4J para utilizar los objetos de esa librería, he logrado que funcione todo excepto el escaneo de los dos lados de la hoja, el escáner que tengo es un *Canon DR-C225*.

Según *Microsoft* y *Wiadef.h*, la propiedad para el escaneo de doble cara es 3088 y se le asigna el valor de 5 (Alimentador automático + Escaneo doble cara):

```
IDevice scanner = dialog.showSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, false, true);
scanner.properties("3088").value(5);
```

El escáner trata de digitalizar la hoja, pero surge un error *(surge por cada hoja que hay en el escáner)*:

> Error: com4j.ComException: 8000ffff Catastrophic failure :
>   Catastrophic failure: .\invoke.cpp:517 at
>   com4j.Wrapper.invoke(Wrapper.java:166) at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.transfer(Unknown Source)

En esta linea:

```
com4jObject = (Com4jObject) item.transfer(wiaFormatJPEG);
img = com4jObject.queryInterface(IImageFile.class);
```

Cuando utilizo el .exe de WIA (wiaacmgr.exe en System32), escanea los dos lados de la hoja sin ningún problema.

Nota: en el foro de Stack Overflow en inglés [he publicado también la pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42957498/duplex-wia-2-0-in-java) para ver si también allí me ayudan, para que por favor si alguien sabe de este tema me ayude con este error, apreciaría mucho su ayuda.

Este es el código completo, cuando escaneo un documento por un solo lado escanea perfecto, pero cuando quiero escanear por los dos lados me surge ese error.

```
   private final String wiaFormatJPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";

    public void acquireImage() {
    try {

        ICommonDialog dialog = ClassFactory.createCommonDialog();
        IDevice scanner = dialog.showSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, false, true);
        IItem item = scanner.items(1);
        IImageFile img;
        Com4jObject com4jObject;

        //Pages to scan in each loop
        scanner.properties("3096").value(1);

        //Duplex property according Microsoft WIA and Wiadef.h
        scanner.properties("3088").value(5);

        //More properties (color, resolution, etc)
        item.properties("6146").value(0);
        item.properties("6147").value(300);
        item.properties("6148").value(300);
        item.properties("6151").value(300 * 8500 / 1000);
        item.properties("6152").value(300 * 11000 / 1000);

        int i = 0;
        boolean hasMorePages = true;
        while (hasMorePages) {
            try {
                //Create DeviceManager
                IDeviceManager manager = ClassFactory.createDeviceManager();

                for (Com4jObject comInfo : manager.deviceInfos()) {
                    IDeviceInfo info = comInfo.queryInterface(IDeviceInfo.class);
                    if (info.deviceID().equals(scanner.deviceID())) {
                        IProperties infoprop = null;
                        infoprop = info.properties();



                        //connect to scanner
                        scanner = info.connect();

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (Integer.parseInt(scanner.properties("3087").value().toString()) != 0) {

                    //transfer the image
                    com4jObject = (Com4jObject) item.transfer(wiaFormatJPEG);
                    img = com4jObject.queryInterface(IImageFile.class);

                    //File to save the images
                    File file = new File(i + ".jpg");

                    if (file.exists()) {
                        //delete the image if exists
                        file.delete();
                    }
                    //Save the image
                    img.saveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

                    //Read and write the image for reduce it weight
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(file);
                    ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", file);

                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                .......Catch the errors
            } finally {
                //properties for document feeder scanner
                IProperty documentHandlingSelect = null;
                IProperty documentHandlingStatus = null;
                for (Com4jObject comProp : scanner.properties()) {
                    IProperty property = comProp.queryInterface(IProperty.class);
                    if (property.propertyID() == 3088) {
                        documentHandlingSelect = property;
                    }
                    if (property.propertyID() == 3087) {
                        documentHandlingStatus = property;
                    }

                }

                hasMorePages = false; //assume that there are no more pages
                if (documentHandlingSelect != null) //required for feeder but unsupported by flatbed
                {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(documentHandlingSelect.value().toString()) != 0) {
                        hasMorePages = (Integer.parseInt(documentHandlingStatus.value().toString()) != 0);
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

    } catch (ComException e) {
        .........Catch the errors
    }
}
```

Comment: qué tipo de librería utilizas para el escáner? Yo he buscado mucho y no he encontrado nada, te agradecería si me dices cuál utilizas

Comment: Hola, mira yo use el método de este enlace de stackoverflow en inglés: [WIA-COM4J](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651923/using-com-objects-with-wia-and-com4j-in-java/4246189) es con una libreria que se llama COM4j se usa con el archivo que se encuentra en System32 llamado wiaaut.dll lo que hace es que lo mapea y saca las clases de este DLL de windows para que puedas utilizar las funciones del escaner desde Java, tambien vi que habia para otros lenguajes pero yo use Java, IMPORTANTE que antes instales los controladores del escáner, Saludos.